# Why are my sort orders not working in my SharePoint 2013 search results Web Part?

Tags: search, search-results, sorting

Currently trying To Show result from Search Result web part, Last Time I Have Face Same issue [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/138133/sorting-not-working-in-the-search-results-web-part-in-sharepoint-2013) ,But last Time m Searching from User Profile,                    Now Currently m Using Search Result web part,trying To display result From List,For that i have use [This Artical](http://habaneroconsulting.com/insights/why-are-my-sort-orders-not-working-in-my-sharepoint-2013-search-results-web-part#.VUBt8yGqpHw) But Still Not working,  any solution for that

,

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried going through a Technet or MSDN link ?

Tryi this link [MSDN](http://blogs.technet.com/b/tothesharepoint/archive/2013/10/08/how-to-change-the-order-in-which-search-results-are-displayed-in-sharepoint-2013.aspx)

hope this helps you out..

Answer (score 1):

This helped me when I had a problem to make the sort order to behave as I wanted: [Why can't I sort the Search Results Web Part by a Managed Property?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/133665/why-cant-i-sort-the-search-results-web-part-by-a-managed-property)

Basically, you need to remove the JSON in order to make the web part sort according to the settings in the query builder. Otherwise the JSON overrides the setings in the query builder.